# Tagging/Encoding Pointers

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I need a way to tag a pointer as being either part of set x or part of set y (ie: the tag has only 2 'states'), I'm that means one can assume untagged = x and tagged = y.

Currently I'm looking at using bitwise xor to do this:

```
ptr ^ magic = encoded_ptr
encoded_ptr ^ magic = ptr
```

but I'm stumped at how to determine if the pointer is tagged in the first place.
I'm using this to mark what pools nodes in a linked list come from, so that when the are delinked, they can go back to the correct perants.

**Update**

Just to make it clear to all those people suggesting to store the flag in extra data members, I'm limited to `sizeof(void*)`, so I can't add new members, else I would have. Also the pools aren't contiguous, they consist of many pages, tracking the ranges would add too much overhead (I'm after a *fast & simple* solution, if one can call it that).

Comment: Why not just use an external `bool` flag stored alongside the pointer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most solution will be platform specific. here a few of them:

1) A pointer returned by `malloc` or `new` will be aligned (4, 8, 16, 32 bytes, you name it). So, on most architectures, several LSB bits of the address will be always 0.

2) And a Win32 specific way: unless your program uses 3GB switch, values of all usermode pointers are less than 0x80000000, so the highest bit can be used as flag. As bonus, it will also crash when the flagged pointer is dereferenced without being repaired.

Comment: I totally forgot about the alignment, so that totally solves my problem, as I can guarantee all the pointers to be aligned to a minimum of 4 :)

Answer (score 9):

There is no safe and portable way to make that sort of thing work.  You might be able to find some system-specific bits that are always a known value (say, the most significant n bits), but that's an extremely fragile and dangerous thing to rely on.  You can't tell whether a pointer is "marked" or not unless some of the bits in the pointer have known values in the first place.

A much better way to do this is to store an identifier in the structure the pointer points to.

Answer (score 2):

Surely if you only have two pools, when you allocate memory for each pool you know the possible address range - so why not check whether your given pointer occurs in one or the other address range with simple pointer arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not a big issue, two std::set's can be used.

If it's important to get this information quickly, and it's acceptable to use only 2-byte aligned pointers, the lowest bit can be used to store this information. But having "hacked" pointers may appear to be quite error-prone...

Answer (score 0):

You might have ptr1 ^ magic = ptr2 with ptr1 in set X and ptr2 in set Y (unless you prove otherwise). Since (I guess) you don't have control on the pointers addresses you are given, your technique seems to be inadequate.

An alternative to Vinay solution is to store the tags as bits of a pre-allocated buffer (specially easy if the size of the list is bounded since you don't have to grow or shrink the buffer). This is a very compact and efficient solution that does not require to modify the pointed data structure.

Cheers,

-stan