# storing flag inside pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have heard quite a lot about storing external data in pointer.
For example in (short string optimization).

For example:

when we want to overload `<<` for our `SSO` class, dependant of the length of the string we want to print either value of pointer or string.

Instead of creating `bool flag` we could encode this flag inside pointer itself. If i am not mistaken its thanks PC architecture that adds padding to prevent unalligned memory access.

But i have yet to see it in example. How could we detect such flag, when binary operation such as `&` to check if RSB or LSB is set to 1 ( as a flag ) are not allowed on pointers? Also wouldnt this mess up dereferencing pointers?

All answers are appreciated.

Comment: There is no portable way to tell a pointer appart from string values if you just have raw data.

Comment: Please pick your poison - C or C++

Comment: afaik in c there is no such thing as "overload <<"

Comment: On many systems, the entire capacity of the pointer (address range) may be used; there are no extra bits.

Comment: AFAIK, the SSO optimization can be keyed off the string length (which is stored in the string class).

Comment: @tobi303: Yes you are correct on this.

Comment: You can create a pointer class that contains the pointer and a `bool` field.  Smart pointers are actually classes.

Comment: Pointer sizes may vary on a PC, depending on the processor and the memory management hardware.  There are 32-bit systems with 32-bit addresses and systems with 64-bit address ranges.  There is also virtual memory and paging.

Comment: "*RSB*"? You mean MSB?

Comment: The guys implementing standard library components, like `std::string`, can do things that we mere mortals cannot. Their code can take advantage of how their compiler works, and that what is formally undefined behavior might be documented to work for that specific compiler. And perhaps only in internal design documents.

Comment: Related: [Tagged Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer), [How portable is using the low bit of a pointer as a flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991506/), [Tagging/Encoding Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586002/)

Answer (score 3):

It is quite possible to do such things (unlike other's have said). Most modern architectures (x86-64, for example) enforce alignment requirements that allow you to use the fact that the least significant bits of a pointer **may** be assumed to be zero, and make use of that storage for other purposes.

Let me pause for a second and say that what I'm about to describe is considered 'undefined behavior' by the C & C++ standard. You are going off-the-rails in a non-portable way by doing what I describe, but there are more standards governing the rules of a computer than the C++ standard (such as the processors assembly reference and architecture docs). Caveat emptor.

With the assumption that we're working on x86_64, let us say that you have a class/structure that starts with a pointer member:

```
struct foo {
    bar * ptr;
    /* other stuff */
};
```

By the x86 architectural constraints, that pointer in foo **must** be aligned on an 8-byte boundary. In this trivial example, you can assume that every pointer to a `struct foo` is therefore an address divisible by 8, meaning the lowest 3 bits of a `foo *` will be zero.

In order to take advantage of such a constraint, you must play some casting games to allow the pointer to be treated as a different type. There's a bunch of different ways of performing the casting, ranging from the old C method (not recommended) of casting it to and from a uintptr_t to cleaner methods of wrapping the pointer in a union. In order to access either the pointer or ancillary data, you need to logically 'and' the datum with a bitmask that zeros out the part of the datum you don't wish.

As an example of this explanation, I wrote an AVL tree a few years ago that sinks the balance book-keeping data into a pointer, and you can take a look at that example here: https://github.com/jschmerge/structures/blob/master/tree/avl_tree.h#L31 (everything you need to see is contained in the struct avl_tree_node at the line I referenced).

Swinging back to a topic you mentioned in your initial question... Short string optimization isn't implemented *quite* the same way. The implementations of it in Clang and GCC's standard libraries differ somewhat, but both boil down to using a union to overload a block of storage with either a pointer or an array of bytes, and play some clever tricks with the string's internal length field for differentiating whether the data is a pointer or local array. For more of the details, this blog post is rather good at explaining: https://shaharmike.com/cpp/std-string/

Answer (score 1):

> "encode this flag inside pointer itself"

No, you are not allowed to do this in either C or C++.

The behaviour on *setting* (let alone *dereferencing*) a pointer to memory you don't own is *undefined* in either language.

Sadly what you want to achieve is to be done at the assembler level, where the distinction between a pointer and integer is sufficiently blurred.