# How to figure out the type of child node without dynamic calls

Tags: c++

I have a tree structure of nodes likes this:

```
struct Node {};
struct ChildNode : Node{};
```

I'll be doing this:

```
Node* n = new ChildNode;
```

At a later point, I need to know the node type:

```
if (IsChildNode(n)) {
    ChildNode* c = static_cast<ChildNode*>(n);
    // ...
}
```

Normally, I do this by adding a virtual `Id()` method to the Node base class, and override that in the derrived class.

In my current case, that's the only method that needs to be virtual, so I'm trying to see if there is a way to avoid the virtual methods while, at the same time, making the Id a compile-time value (not a non-const member-variable in Node class).

Is there a way to figure out the type of ChildNode without:

- using dynamic_cast
- Without using a virtual function
- Without setting a runtime variable in the Node class.

I'm using C++ 17, on Visual Studio 2019

Comment: You have however not a [mcve].

Comment: "*Is there a way to figure out the type of ChildNode without: - using dynamic_cast - Without using a virtual function - Without setting a runtime variable in the Node class*" - you have pretty much eliminated all of the possible options. Those are the only ways I know to identify a type at runtime. Also, `dynamic_cast` does not work if a type does not have at least 1 virtual method, even if it is just the destructor. If you don't want the overhead of using RTTI, then using an int/enum data member is the simplest way to go.

Comment: _ll be doing this:

`Node* n = new ChildNode`_ - now pretend that you never need to do that.

Comment: "`Forgot to mention, without this, also ....:` -  Is this worth *your*  time?  If so - Why?

Comment: In short: You cannot do this at compile time. You need to determine the type of the child at runtime with your current design (which is a strong indicator its flawed). You ma have a look into the _Visitor Design Pattern_ and _interfaces_.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I stated that I normally do this with virtual calls. Getting this done at runtime is easy; that's not the point. The point is to device a way to still be able to figure out the info a runtime without virtual calls, or without using member variables in the base class, or without using a template parameter.

Comment: @Dess You can have a look at the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to achieve _Static Polymorphism_, though you'll end up seeing that doesn't really solve your problem at hand.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: *no template parameter*

Comment: @Dess No, that's not possible without. Check [@Remy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606838/how-to-figure-out-the-type-of-child-node-without-dynamic-calls?noredirect=1#comment99789544_56606838) again. I can write up an answer that what you want isn't possible in c++ if you'll be satisfied with this.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Saying that you, or I, or Remy don't know how to do it is not an answer to the question. An answer would be to specify *why* it can't be done. Maybe it can be done, maybe it can't, but I'm looking for definitive answer, not prove by omission.

Comment: @Dess _"Saying that you, or I, or Remy don't know how to do it is not an answer to the question."_ Well good luck then. There's no answer for what you're asking. At least not with the current c++ standards.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Of course there is an answer. I don't know it, and neither do you, but maybe someone does. Maybe the answer is what Remy says, but if that's the case, then I'd like to hear that being articulated in terms of the standard spec. Like, "per the spec, those are the only ways to do that". I'd be satisfied with an answer like that. Let's see if some language lawyer stops by and drops an answer.

Comment: @Dess _"and neither do you"_ I well know the answer is: You cannot do this with the requirements you setup.

Comment: There's four places this information can be stored: in a constant, in a type parameter, in a field, or through RTTI (which requires a vtable). You've eliminated all those places, so where else are you gonna put it?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: Clarification: I didn't eliminate constants from the solution space.

Comment: obviously you have each type of child allocated with a different allocator so you only have to ask the allocators if they created that instance! (*please for the love of god don't do that*)

Answer (score 1):

In broad terms, you have a pointer and an object being pointed to:

```
Node*           ChildNode
+------+        +------------------
| XXXX | -----> | ... some data ... 
+------+        +------------------
```

If you need to determine the type of the pointed object at run-time, eliminating the static type-system as an option (which includes templates), then these two places are the *only* sources of information.

By denying use of `dynamic_cast` and `virtual` functions, you've eliminated C++'s built-in mechanisms for dynamic type information. And by denying use of a member variable, you've also eliminated the possibility of manually implementing type-checking in a similar manner. Unless the different `Node` types have some other unique value stored in the object, there is no way to use the value of object pointed at to determine its type.

However, the pointer itself can be a source of information. For example, with standard usage, the pointer can indicate that it does actually point to an object via comparison to null. I jokingly pointed out in the comments that you can use unique allocators for each `Node` type that can identify their own pointers; but given the constraints, it *is* an option. This would have to be implemented via:

- an adjacently allocated value (but that would benear  identical to a member variable)
- some sort of lookup (which could be very very slow)
- a [tagged pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586002/tagging-encoding-pointers) (very very non-standard and fragile)

None of these options are good in the slightest. RTTI and member variables are both very common ways of solving your problem. I do not encourage you to use *any* of the mechanisms listed above.

I can't answer using the spec since proving a negative is impossible. However, I hope I've shown that conceptually, there are very few options.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at how LLVM does their casting. Almost certainly, their implementation will be as a fast as it gets. Here are some documents regarding this:

https://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html

http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates

https://llvm.org/doxygen/Casting_8h_source.html

Essentially, they have a setup like this:

```
enum class Kind {
    ChildNode
};

struct Node {
    Node(Kind k) : kind(k) {}
    const Kind kind;
};

struct ChildNode : Node {
    ChildNode() : Node(Kind::ChildNode) {}

    static bool classof(const Node* n) { return n->kind == Kind::ChildNode;}
};
```

Then, they do some template trickery to define a generic function:

```
bool isa<TypeToCheckFor, CurrentType>(const CurrentType& t);
```

Which can be called to check the type.

Although this version doesn't meet this one bullet point of mine:

```
* Without setting a runtime variable in the Node class.
```

At least, it uses a const base type member, no virtual calls, and const parameters. That will be as optimal of a setup as the compiler can have to perform as much optimization on these checks as possible.